# How to know a domain name server in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want a vb.net function. We give domain name, it gives the name servers and the IP.

What would the code be?

I know I can use webclient to scrap various whois sites. They don't like that and put password. I want the "good" way to do it.

Say google.com's name server is ns1.google.com I want to know what's the name server of google.com.

For example:

If we go to http://who.is/whois/google.com/

We will see that google.com has ns1.google.com ns2.google.com ns3.google.com and ns4.google.com

I want a function say `FindNS("Google.com")` to yield `"ns1.google.com"`

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("ns1.google.com").AddressList;
```

This will return an array of all IPs linked to the hostname you provide.

Comment: What about the name server?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking. It sounds like your asking if this will work with a DNS name. If thats right then this will work.

Comment: Say google.com's name server is ns1.google.com I want to know that.

Comment: I've update the code as the previous version was depreciated. This code will work with dns names.